# OpenGL light only shining one way

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm playing around with OpenGL in Java (LWJGL) and am attempting to add lighting.
I've added enabled a light but it only shines in one direction.

Here is an image illustrating how the light works: [image: Light shining only one direction]

The following code is run every time the scene is rendered

```
FloatBuffer lightPos = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
lightPos.put(new float[]{0f,-2f,0f,1f});
lightPos.flip();

FloatBuffer LightDiffuse = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
LightDiffuse.put(new float[]{1f,1f,0f,0f});
LightDiffuse.flip();

GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, LightDiffuse);
GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_POSITION, lightPos);
GL11.glLightf(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0.6f);
```

The following code is run in the beginning of the program to initialize everything

```
GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);      
GL11.glClearDepth(1.0);                 
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);      
GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);       
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT1);
GL11.glLightf(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0.5f);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION); 
GLU.gluPerspective(
  80.0f,
  (float) displayMode.getWidth() / (float) displayMode.getHeight(),
  0.1f,
  500.0f);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW); 
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
```

My question is then: Why is the light acting this way and what must I change?

Comment: It is probably the light type. This might be a spot light which has a direction associated with it. Can you switch to a point light. I can't see where you specify the type as 'Spot' , but it may be the default type.

Comment: @ArunR: The fixed function pipeline's default light type is omnidirectional.

Comment: Are you sure that the normals for the object are correct?